# OpenCV streamming ip camera always return False

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture, ip-camera

So far I have used OpenCV for streamming ip camera from Raspberry pi + pi camera. I want to save the video from ip camera with codec H.264 and it didn't work. I find out from this post https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/100 which told me that only manually built opencv library would support H264 codec.
So i followed this link to manually build opencv https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-ubuntu/ and succeeded. **But when I use manually built opencv, I can no longer access my ip camera**, the **cap.open()** always return None. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("http://10.10.1.240:8081/")
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame2 = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    cv2.imshow("frame2", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(25)
    if key == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

In the above code, **ret is always False**. 
I have been stucked in this for 2 days without a real solution and explaination. Any help would be appriciated, thanks!

Comment: are you sure the url is right? Can you stream this url with VLC media player? Typically such streams are rtsp streams instead. Prebuild opencv can decode h264 too in newer versions.

Comment: Hi @Micka, for your questions: I'm sure the url is right, I'm using raspberry kit + pi camera module v2+ motion service, I still be able to stream ip camera via web browser at url : http://10.10.1.240:8081/. And I did install prebuild opencv with lastest version (3.4.2) but it does not support h264. When I try to use VideoWriter with fourcc(*'X264') and tried to save the recorded video as .mp4, I received this error:  OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x34363258/'X264' is not supported with codec id 27 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'

Comment: h264 encoding isnt supported by default, but decoding should be included.

Answer (score 1):

> But when I use manually built opencv, I can no longer access my ip camera, the cap.open() always returns none.

Have you tried, checking if your ip camera is working properly and present on your network after building opencv from source? Did you try to stream from the camera using any media player after installation off opencv from source?.

As far as your code is concerned, try the following format for cv2.VideoCapture

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
cap.open("rtsp://yourusername:yourpassword@172.16.30.248:555/Streaming/channels/2/")
```

yourusername-username given to your ip camera.
yourpassword-password for the given user name.

You can try the following as well.

```
cv2.VideoCapture("rstp://admin:PASSWORD@192.168.1.64/doc/page/previw.asp")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Ashish,Thank you for your answer!  I did try to check my ip camera, since I'm using raspberry pi + motion service so I can stream my camera using web browser at url: http://10.10.1.240:8081/, it's working fine. The problem come up when I try to access it using python and opencv using the block of code above.

Comment: Hi @kitetan612, Did you try to modify the code and test again?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the ip address of your computer and your camera are in the same subnet mask.